# ProcessBuilder hangs when running freebcp

Tags: java, unix, processbuilder, freebcp

I have following code:

```
String[] command = {freeBcp,dbName + "." + dbUsername + "." + tableName,"in",file.getPath(),"-S" + dbServer,"-c","-t,","&"};
    log.info("Invoking command: " + Arrays.toString(command));
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        int exitValue = -1;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            log.info("BCP PROCESS: " + line);
        }
        log.debug("Close output stream..");
        process.getOutputStream().close();
        log.debug("Close error stream..");
        process.getErrorStream().close();
        log.debug("Close input stream..");
        process.getInputStream().close();
        log.debug("Waiting for freebcp Process to terminate..");
        exitValue = process.waitFor();
        if (exitValue == 0) {
            log.debug("Exit value is 0..");
            return true;
        } else {
            log.debug("Exit value is " + exitValue +"..");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("BCP PROCESS", e);
        throw new BulkCopyException("Failed to bcp file (" + file.getPath() + ")", e);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("BCP PROCESS", e);
        throw new BulkCopyException("Failed to bcp file (" + file.getPath() + ")", e);
    }
```

which runs the freebcp process, prints out "Exit value is 0.." so the process is finished but it just stops and never calls the return statement.

If I run the command in Putty it runs fine as expected. Any clues what the issue could be?

Here's what I get in the log:

```
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS:
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: Starting copy...
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 1000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 2000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 3000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 4000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 5000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 6000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 7000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 8000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 9000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 10000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 11000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 12000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 13000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 14000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 15000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 16000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 17000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 18000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 19000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 20000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 21000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 22000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 23000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 24000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 25000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 26000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 27000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 28000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 29000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 30000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 31000 rows sent to SQL Server.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [INFO] BCP PROCESS: 31660 rows copied.
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [DEBUG] Close output stream..
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [DEBUG] Close error stream..
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [DEBUG] Close input stream..
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [DEBUG] Waiting for freebcp Process to terminate..
2014-04-07 14:48:07 BulkCopy taskExecutor-1 [DEBUG] Exit value is 0..
```

Comment: try to sysout whole command and than run generated command via putty, and check what happens. Also remember to include `/bin/sh -c` in putty as you are using such argument in process builder

Comment: Are you sure the "process" you get is not sh itself that has finished running freebcp but is still running itself? Why do you not call freebcp directly?

Comment: I have used the same pattern to run another process and it's all fine and exits as expected. It makes no difference if I run this one directly or not, it still hangs at the process.waitFor() line